# Sci-fi Series about five teens who find a spaceship and fly to Mars to get away from the US government

Tags: story-identification

Five teens find/steal/otherwise aquire a spaceship that flies around a bit before landing and setting up a shield on Earth. The US military tries to break through the shield with tanks and eventually a nuke, which doesn't work. The military calls the ship "Caeser" or "Codename Caeser" or maybe "Czar".

The ship then flies to Mars where the five teens are trained to use the weapons on the ship/how to fly it by a general that wound up on the ship with them somehow. I remember they were near Olympus Mons for some plot point. They also get taught how to play instruments?

At some point, one of the teens gets injured and his heart is replaced with a machine that constantly pumps his blood instead of beating.

Comment: Welcome to the site. To clarify, is this a book series or a TV series? Also, when did you read/watch it?

Comment: If not a book, was it animated or live action?